# Prove that $(n+1)^n < n^{n+1}$ for all $n>3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, contest-math

> Prove that $(n+1)^n < n^{n+1}$ for all $n>3$

At $n=4$, $$5^4<4^5$$  which is indeed true.

By mathematical induction, we need to prove that $$(n+2)^{n+1} < (n+1)^{n+2}$$

$$\implies (n+2)^n\times (n+2) < (n+1)^n\times(n+1)^2 $$

I am not getting how to proceed further than this. Any hints or help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: divide everything by $n^n$

Comment: To check, must you use induction, or are you hoping that you can use induction?

Comment: Hoping actually. Although a proof using mathematical induction would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof by induction:

Base case: Done by OP.

Induction step:

Notice that $(n+1)^{2(n+1) } = (n^2 + 2n + 1) ^ {n+1} > [ (n)(n+2) ] ^ {n+1}$.

> Since $ (n+1) ^ n < n^ {n+1} $ by the induction hypothesis,
>  so $ [ (n)(n+2) ] ^ {n+1} < (n+1)^{2(n+1) } < (n+1) ^ {n+2} n ^ {n+1} $,

hence it follows that $(n+2)^{n+1} < (n+1)^{n+2}$.

---

Notes

- The "notice that" step might initially seem like magic. However, you can backtrack it to see why that's something we would have cared about.
- If that didn't work, we could have tried to prove (say) $(n+1)^{kn+2k-2 } > [n (n+2) ^{k-1}] ^{n+1}$, which would eventually be true for large enough $k$.
- I was previously skeptical that an induction solution existed, because the standard/naive routes didn't seem to result in a $(n+2)$ term, nor was it clear how a $(n+2)^{n+1}$ could be related to a $(n+1)^{n}$. I'm glad to have figured this out.

Answer (score 4):

The claim is equivalent to  $\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n < n$. The sequence on the LHS, whose limit is $e$, is known to remain in the set $[2,3]$. If you can use this fact, the result you want to prove must hold for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: -1 To me, you're replacing the problem statement with a similar (unproven) statement, so that is of no help. It would have been better if you could demonstrate (say) that $ ( 1 + 1/n)^n < e $.

Comment: @CalvinLin The point is that, during a course, a sequence of results is proven. It may be the case that the result I mention is already known at this time. This is why I explicitly say "If you can use this fact (...)".

Comment: OP used tag of "Algebra-precalculus", so I disagree that your assumption is reasonable. Of course, it might apply to someone who's already in calculus or analysis.

Comment: @CalvinLin You have a point, I did not check the tags... But I will keep the answer as it may be useful for other members.

Answer (score 3):

Using binomial expansion, we can write
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &= (n+1)^n\\
&= (n+1)^{n-1}\times (n+1)\\
&= \left[n^{n-1} + {n-1 \choose 1}n^{n-2} + {n-1 \choose 2}n^{n-3} + \cdots + {n-1 \choose n-2}n + {n-1 \choose n-1}\right] \times (n+1)\\
&= \left[n^{n-1} + {n-1 \choose 1}n^{n-2} + {n-1 \choose 2}n^{n-3} + \cdots + {n-1 \choose n-2}n\right] \times (n+1) + (n+1)\\
\end{align*}
For $n > 3$, it is straightforward to show that
$${n-1 \choose k} < n^k$$
for all $k = 1,2,\dots, n-2$. Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{LHS} &< \left[n^{n-1} + n^1n^{n-2} + n^2n^{n-3} + \cdots + n^{n-2}n\right] \times (n+1) + (n+1)\\
&= \left[(n-1)n^{n-1}\right] \times (n+1) + (n+1)\\
&= (n^2 - 1)n^{n-1} + (n+1)\\
&= n^{n+1} - n^{n-1} + (n+1)\\
&< n^{n+1} = \text{RHS},
\end{align*}
where the last step follows from the fact that
$$n^{n-1} > n+1$$
for all $n > 3$.

Remark: In contrast to other answers, this gives a proof without using induction.

Comment: In your first paragraph, how did you pull out an additional $ n+1$ factor on the right?

Comment: One way to adapt what you have is to use $ { n \choose k } < n^k / k!$ and thus $ (n+1)^n  = ( n^n + { n\choose 1 } n^{n-1} + \ldots ) < n^n ( 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + ... ) < n^n e < n^{n+1}$

Comment: @CalvinLin This is a neat one, thanks! For your first comment, could I ask which specific step are you referring to?

Comment: The 4th equality in "$LHS = ... = ... = ... = $" doesn't make sense to me. You might be doing some algebraic manipulations that I'm not aware of, but it seems like you merely 1) Reduced the value of the bracket by ${n-1 \choose n-1} = 1$, and 2) Multiplied by $n+1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, indeed. ${n-1 \choose n-1}$ was first reduced to 1, and then separated out of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

As [noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113751/prove-that-n1n-nn1-for-all-n3#comment8505937_4113751) by [Exodd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/161426/exodd), consider the equivalent problem $(1 + 1/n)^n < n$ (also [offered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4113776/300912) by [PierreCarre](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/639238/pierrecarre)). If one does not have the relationship with $\mathrm e < 3$ available, prove the equivalent problem by induction instead:

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right)^n \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right) < n\left(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}\right)<n+1.$$

The base case is $625/256 < 4$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(n+2)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n}} < \frac{(n+1)^{n+2}}{n^{n+1}}$

$\frac{((n+2)n)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n}} < \frac{(n+1)^{n+2}}{n^{n+1}}$

$((n+2)n)^{n+1} < (n+1)^{2(n+1)}$

$(n+2)n < (n+1)^{2}$

And it demonstrates the induction step!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-inductive proof that involves a nice application of the AM-GM inequality.

It suffices for us to prove the following inequality:
\begin{align}
\forall \ & n>3,  \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n <4 \\
& \iff \left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^n <4 \\
& \iff \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^n >\dfrac{1}{4} \\
& \iff \dfrac{n}{n+1} > \sqrt[^n]{\dfrac{1}{4}}
\end{align}

But
\begin{align}
\sqrt[^n]{\dfrac{1}{4}} &= \sqrt[^n]{\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1^{n-2}} \\
& \leq \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}+ \dfrac{1}{2}+n-2}{n} (\text{By the AM-GM Inequality}) \\
& = \dfrac{n-1}{n}.
\end{align}

It remains to show that $\dfrac{n-1}{n} < \dfrac{n}{n+1}$, which is obvious since $n^2-1 < n^2$.